# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Does not connect

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

I have tried to reinstall my SQL Server 2008 several times but for the life of me, I cannot get past the "Connect to Server" screen. it just stays "connecting" forever. I am trying to connect to ./sqlexpress and it just goes on and on. I also tried connecting to another server and that one did not work as well. I have tried that 2nd server connection on a separate machine and that did not work as well so I'm sure it is my computer.

I have just completed a fresh install of SQL server, I went through tons of steps to uninstall it and hoped that a fresh installation would fix it as it had been working at some point before.

I am kind of at a loss here and had no luck googling this particular problem.

[image]

EDIT:

Also corrected server name...

[image]

MORE EDIT:

I was able to run some .bat files to set up some default testing databases, it drops if they exist and recreates essentially. Those ran without an issue but I still can't get past the "Connect to Server"

Comment: *"I have tried that 2nd server connection on a separate machine and that did not work as well so I'm sure it is my computer."* did the connection to any other sql instance work from a separate machine?

Comment: Yes, basically the app I work on has a local database and that 2nd server is just part of another project but not hosted on my local machine. Both used to work and work on another machine.

Comment: if you are able to connect to some other instance of sql server and not your local instance, it could be that the instance is not running or the network protocols are not configured properly.

Answer (score 1):

you should try to click the dropdown field server name and search for other servers. This should list the available databases.

Also, is the mssql service running?

Sebastian

Comment: I don't see a mssql service running, only these: SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) auto/started. SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRSS) auto (just switched it from disabled). SQL Server Browser disabled, SQL Reporting Services (SQLEXPRESS) auto/started, SQL Server VSS Writer auto/started

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Your server name looks odd, especially the "./" in front of the sqlexpress. 
Try putting in your server name + "\sqlexpress". As an example

```
  winserver2008\sqlexpress
```

or maybe just

```
  sqlexpress
```

Comment: yea, I realized I had "/" instead of "\" first of all. Normally I was able to connect to ".\sqlexpress" without a problem.

Comment: Does it work now? Did either of my suggestions get you any further?

Comment: no, but it works now by some random miracle. I uninstalled and reinstalled and it wasn't broken before the uninstall.